# Recreate job or delete old job on every helm install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have created Kubernetes job and job got created, but it is failing on deployment to the Kubernetes cluster. When I try to redeploy it using Helm the job is not redeploying (deleting old job and recreating new one, unlike a microservice deployment).

How can I achieve this redeploying job without manually deleting it in Kubernetes? Could I tell it to recreate the container?

`job.yaml` contains:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-init-job"
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: disabled
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,pre-delete
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}-init-service-account
      containers:
        - name: app-installer
          image: some image
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - echo Hello executing k8s init-container
          securityContext:
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Job is not getting redeployed

```
kubectl get jobs -n namespace

NAME                    COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
test-init-job   0/1           13h        13h
```

kubectl describe job test-init-job -n test

```
Name:           test-init-job
Namespace:      test
Selector:       controller-uid=86370470-0964-42d5-a9c1-00c8a462239f
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
                meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Fri, 14 Oct 2022 18:03:31 +0530
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 1 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           controller-uid=86370470-0964-42d5-a9c1-00c8a462239f
                    job-name=test-init-job
  Annotations:      helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
                    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
                    helm.sh/hook-weight: -5
                    linkerd.io/inject: disabled
  Service Account:  test-init-service-account
  Containers:
   test-app-installer:
    Image:      artifactory/test-init-container:1.0.0
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Environment:
      test.baseUrl:         baser
      test.authType:        basic
      test.basic.username:  jack
      test.basic.password:  password
    Mounts:
      /etc/test/config from test-installer-config-vol (ro)
  Volumes:
   test-installer-config-vol:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      test-installer-config-files
    Optional:  false
Events:        <none>
```

Comment: When you redeploy it, has anything changed?  The general model for a Job is that it will run exactly once, and IME it can cause problems when you try to manage it in Helm.  Does adding a [Helm hook annotation](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) make it run in the way you expect?  (I can expand further on that, if it's the behavior you want.)

Comment: I have updated yaml file i tried with hooks . I want job to recreated/redeployed every time when I do helm install. but job is not been deleted automatically and it throws exception. I need to delete it manually to redeploy the job .

Comment: With the Helm hook annotations you've added in I would expect every `helm upgrade` command to delete and recreate the Job.  It's possible you'll need to delete it once more before running the first upgrade.

Comment: kubectl get jobs -n namespace
NAME                    COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
test-init-job     0/1           13h        13h

Comment: it is not getting redeployed

Answer (score 6):

Jobs cannot be redeployed, because their template is immutable.

If you get a message `cannot patch "..." with kind Job: Job.batch "db-sync-download-snapshot" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: ... field is immutable`, this is the reason.

Just delete a job, or create it with a `$VERSION` appended to a name.

With GitOps, `$VERSION` should be `$CI_COMMIT_HASH`.

Replace the `name` within the Helm template:

```
  metadata:
    name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-init-job-{{ .Release.revision }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

set `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`, see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).